# point inside a polygon with edges parallel to the axes

Tags: c#, java, c++, python, algorithm

I've solved Polygon problem problem at interviewstreet, but it seems too slow. What is the best solution to the problem?

There are N points on X-Y plane with integer coordinates (xi, yi). You are given a set of polygons with all of its edges parallel to the axes (in other words, all angles of the polygons are 90 degree angles and all lines are in the cardinal directions. There are no diagonals). For each polygon your program should find the number of points lying inside it (A point located on the border of polygon is also considered to be inside the polygon).

Input:

First line two integers N and Q. Next line contains N space separated integer coordinates (xi,yi). Q queries follow. Each query consists of a single integer Mi in the first line, followed by Mi space separated integer coordinates (x[i][j],y[i][j]) specifying the boundary of the query polygon in clock-wise order.

Polygon is an alternating sequence of vertical line segments and horizontal line segments.
    Polygon has Mi edges, where (x[i][j],y[i][j]) is connected to (x[i][(j+1)%Mi], y[i][(j+1)%Mi].
    For each 0 <= j < Mi, either x[i][(j+1)%Mi] == x[i][j] or y[i][(j+1)%Mi] == y[i][j] but not both.
    It is also guaranteed that the polygon is not self-intersecting.

Output:

For each query output the number of points inside the query polygon in a separate line.

Sample Input #1:

```
16 2
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 0
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 0
3 1
3 2
3 3
8
0 0
0 1
1 1
1 2
0 2
0 3
3 3
3 0
4
0 0
0 1
1 1
1 0
```

Sample Output #1:

```
16
4
```

[image]

Sample Input #2:

```
6 1
1 1
3 3
3 5
5 2
6 3
7 4
10
1 3
1 6
4 6
4 3
6 3
6 1
4 1
4 2
3 2
3 3
```

Sample Output #2:

```
4
```

[image]

Constraints:

1 <= N <= 20,000
1 <= Q <= 20,000
4 <= Mi <= 20
Each co-ordinate would have a value of atmost 200,000

I am interested in solutions in mentioned languages or pseudo code.

EDIT: here is my code but it's O(n^2)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Polygon
{
// avoding System.Drawing dependency
public struct Point
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
        : this()
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return X ^ Y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        return obj is Point && this == (Point)obj;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Point a, Point b)
    {
        return a.X == b.X && a.Y == b.Y;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Point a, Point b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
}

public class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BasicTestCase();
        CustomTestCase();
        // to read from STDIN
        //string firstParamsLine = Console.ReadLine();
        //var separator = new char[] { ' ' };
        //var firstParams = firstParamsLine.Split(separator);
        //int N = int.Parse(firstParams[0]);
        //int Q = int.Parse(firstParams[1]);

        //List<Point> points = new List<Point>(N);

        //for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        //{
        //    var coordinates = Console.ReadLine().Split(separator);
        //    points.Add(new Point(int.Parse(coordinates[0]), int.Parse(coordinates[1])));
        //}

        //var polygons = new List<List<Point>>(Q); // to reduce realocation
        //for (int i = 0; i < Q; i++)
        //{

        //    var firstQ = Console.ReadLine().Split(separator);
        //    int coordinatesLength = int.Parse(firstQ[0]);
        //    var polygon = new List<Point>(coordinatesLength);
        //    for (int j = 0; j < coordinatesLength; j++)
        //    {
        //        var coordinates = Console.ReadLine().Split(separator);
        //        polygon.Add(new Point(int.Parse(coordinates[0]), int.Parse(coordinates[1])));
        //    }
        //    polygons.Add(polygon);
        //}

        //foreach (var polygon in polygons)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(CountPointsInPolygon(points, polygon));
        //}


    }

    private static void BasicTestCase()
    {
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>(){ new Point(0, 0),
                                                new Point(0, 1),
                                                new Point(0, 2),
                                                new Point(0, 3),
                                                new Point(1, 0),
                                                new Point(1, 1),
                                                new Point(1, 2),
                                                new Point(1, 3),
                                                new Point(2, 0),
                                                new Point(2, 1),
                                                new Point(2, 2),
                                                new Point(2, 3),
                                                new Point(3, 0),
                                                new Point(3, 1),
                                                new Point(3, 2),
                                                new Point(3, 3) };

        List<Point> polygon1 = new List<Point>(){   new Point(0, 0),
                                                    new Point(0, 1),
                                                    new Point(2, 1),
                                                    new Point(2, 2),
                                                    new Point(0, 2),
                                                    new Point(0, 3),
                                                    new Point(3, 3),
                                                    new Point(3, 0)};

        List<Point> polygon2 = new List<Point>(){   new Point(0, 0),
                                                    new Point(0, 1),
                                                    new Point(1, 1),
                                                    new Point(1, 0),};

        Console.WriteLine(CountPointsInPolygon(points, polygon1));
        Console.WriteLine(CountPointsInPolygon(points, polygon2));

        List<Point> points2 = new List<Point>(){new Point(1, 1),
                                                new Point(3, 3),
                                                new Point(3, 5),
                                                new Point(5, 2),
                                                new Point(6, 3),
                                                new Point(7, 4),};

        List<Point> polygon3 = new List<Point>(){   new Point(1, 3),
                                                    new Point(1, 6),
                                                    new Point(4, 6),
                                                    new Point(4, 3),
                                                    new Point(6, 3),

                                                    new Point(6, 1),
                                                    new Point(4, 1),
                                                    new Point(4, 2),
                                                    new Point(3, 2),
                                                    new Point(3, 3),};

        Console.WriteLine(CountPointsInPolygon(points2, polygon3));
    }

    private static void CustomTestCase()
    {
        // generated 20 000 points and polygons
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"in3.txt"))
        {
            string firstParamsLine = file.ReadLine();
            var separator = new char[] { ' ' };
            var firstParams = firstParamsLine.Split(separator);
            int N = int.Parse(firstParams[0]);
            int Q = int.Parse(firstParams[1]);

            List<Point> pointsFromFile = new List<Point>(N);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                var coordinates = file.ReadLine().Split(separator);
                pointsFromFile.Add(new Point(int.Parse(coordinates[0]), int.Parse(coordinates[1])));
            }

            var polygons = new List<List<Point>>(Q); // to reduce realocation
            for (int i = 0; i < Q; i++)
            {

                var firstQ = file.ReadLine().Split(separator);
                int coordinatesLength = int.Parse(firstQ[0]);
                var polygon = new List<Point>(coordinatesLength);
                for (int j = 0; j < coordinatesLength; j++)
                {
                    var coordinates = file.ReadLine().Split(separator);
                    polygon.Add(new Point(int.Parse(coordinates[0]), int.Parse(coordinates[1])));
                }
                polygons.Add(polygon);
            }

            foreach (var polygon in polygons)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(CountPointsInPolygon(pointsFromFile, polygon));
            }

        }
    }

    public static int CountPointsInPolygon(List<Point> points, List<Point> polygon)
    {
        // TODO input check
        polygon.Add(polygon[0]); // for simlicity
        // check if any point is outside of the bounding box of the polygon
        var minXpolygon = polygon.Min(p => p.X);
        var maxXpolygon = polygon.Max(p => p.X);
        var minYpolygon = polygon.Min(p => p.Y);
        var maxYpolygon = polygon.Max(p => p.Y);
        // ray casting algorithm (form max X moving to point)
        int insidePolygon = 0;
        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            if (point.X >= minXpolygon && point.X <= maxXpolygon && point.Y >= minYpolygon && point.Y <= maxYpolygon)
            {       // now points are inside the bounding box 
                    isPointsInside(polygon, point, ref insidePolygon);
            } // else outside
        }
        return insidePolygon;

    }
    private static void isPointsInside(List<Point> polygon, Point point, ref int insidePolygon)
    {
        int intersections = 0;    

        for (int i = 0; i < polygon.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (polygon[i] == point)
            {
                insidePolygon++;
                return;
            }
            if (point.isOnEdge(polygon[i], polygon[i + 1]))
            {
                insidePolygon++;
                return;
            }
            if (Helper.areIntersecting(polygon[i], polygon[i + 1], point))
            {
                intersections++;
            }
        }

        if (intersections % 2 != 0)
        {
            insidePolygon++;
        }   
    }
}

static class Helper
{
    public static bool isOnEdge(this Point point, Point first, Point next)
    {
            // onVertical 
            if (point.X == first.X && point.X == next.X && point.Y.InRange(first.Y, next.Y))
            {
                return true;
            }
            //onHorizontal 
            if (point.Y == first.Y && point.Y == next.Y && point.X.InRange(first.X, next.X))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
    }

    public static bool InRange(this int value, int first, int second)
    {
        if (first <= second)
        {
            return value >= first && value <= second;
        }
        else
        {
            return value >= second && value <= first;
        }
    }

    public static bool areIntersecting(Point polygonPoint1, Point polygonPoint2, Point vector2End)
    {
        // "move" ray up for 0.5 to avoid problem with parallel edges
        if (vector2End.X < polygonPoint1.X )
        {
            var y = (vector2End.Y + 0.5);
            var first = polygonPoint1.Y;
            var second = polygonPoint2.Y;
            if (first <= second)
            {
                return y >= first && y <= second;
            }
            else
            {
                return y >= second && y <= first;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer in makemycode.stackexchange.com (just kidding)

Comment: Which language would you like your answer in?

Comment: any? even word description and something better then ray casting :)

Comment: if you posted some sample code then people might suggest improvements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution from authors - a bit obfuscated, isn't it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

typedef long long int64;
const int N = 100000, X = 2000000001;
const int Q = 100000, PQ = 20;
struct Point {
    int x, y, idx;
    Point(int _x = 0, int _y = 0, int _idx = 0) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        idx = _idx;
    }
} arr_x[N], arr_y[N];
struct VLineSegment {
    int x, y1, y2, idx, sign;
    VLineSegment(int _x = 0, int _y1 = 0, int _y2 = 0, int _sign = 1, int _idx = 0) {
        x = _x;
        y1 = _y1;
        y2 = _y2;
        sign = _sign;
        idx = _idx;
    }
    bool operator<(const VLineSegment& v) const {
        return x < v.x;
    }
} segs[Q * PQ];

struct TreeNode {
    int idx1, idx2, cnt;
    TreeNode *left, *right;
    TreeNode() { left = right = 0; cnt = 0; }
    ~TreeNode() { if(left) delete left; if(right) delete right; }

    void update_stat() {
        cnt = left->cnt + right->cnt;
    }

    void build(Point* arr, int from, int to, bool empty) {
        idx1 = from;
        idx2 = to;
        if(from == to) {
            if(!empty) {
                cnt = 1;
            } else { 
                cnt = 0;
            }
        } else {
            left = new TreeNode();
            right = new TreeNode();
            int mid = (from + to) / 2;
            left->build(arr, from, mid, empty);
            right->build(arr, mid + 1, to, empty);
            update_stat();
        }
    }
    void update(Point& p, bool add) {
        if(p.idx >= idx1 && p.idx <= idx2) {
            if(idx1 != idx2) {
                left->update(p, add);
                right->update(p, add);
                update_stat();
            } else {
                if(add) {
                    cnt = 1;
                } else {
                    cnt = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int query(int ya, int yb) {
        int y1 = arr_y[idx1].y, y2 = arr_y[idx2].y;
        if(ya <= y1 && y2 <= yb) {
            return cnt;
        } else if(max(ya, y1) <= min(yb, y2)) {
            return left->query(ya, yb) + right->query(ya, yb);
        }
        return 0;
    }
};

bool cmp_x(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    return a.x < b.x;
}
bool cmp_y(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    return a.y < b.y;
}

void calc_ys(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int sign, int& ya, int& yb) {
    if(x2 < x3) {
        yb = 2 * y2 - sign;
    } else {
        yb = 2 * y2 + sign;
    }
    if(x2 < x1) {
        ya = 2 * y1 + sign;
    } else {
        ya = 2 * y1 - sign;
    }
}

bool process_polygon(int* x, int* y, int cnt, int &idx, int i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < cnt; j ++) {
        //cerr << x[(j + 1) % cnt] - x[j] << "," << y[(j + 1) % cnt] - y[j] << endl;
        if(x[j] == x[(j + 1) % cnt]) {
            int _x, y1, y2, sign;
            if(y[j] < y[(j + 1) % cnt]) {
                _x = x[j] * 2 - 1;
                sign = -1;
                calc_ys(x[(j + cnt - 1) % cnt], y[j], x[j], y[(j + 1) % cnt], x[(j + 2) % cnt], sign, y1, y2);
            } else {
                _x = x[j] * 2 + 1;
                sign = 1;
                calc_ys(x[(j + 2) % cnt], y[(j + 2) % cnt], x[j], y[j], x[(j + cnt - 1) % cnt], sign, y1, y2);
            }
            segs[idx++] = VLineSegment(_x, y1, y2, sign, i);
        }
    }
}
int results[Q];

int n, q, c;

int main() {
    int cl = clock();
    cin >> n >> q;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        cin >> arr_y[i].x >> arr_y[i].y;
        arr_y[i].x *= 2;
        arr_y[i].y *= 2;
    }
    int idx = 0, cnt, x[PQ], y[PQ];
    for(int i = 0; i < q; i ++) {
        cin >> cnt;
        for(int j = 0; j < cnt; j ++) cin >> x[j] >> y[j];
        process_polygon(x, y, cnt, idx, i);
    }
    sort(segs, segs + idx);
    memset(results, 0, sizeof results);
    sort(arr_y, arr_y + n, cmp_y);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        arr_y[i].idx = i;
        arr_x[i] = arr_y[i];
    }
    sort(arr_x, arr_x + n, cmp_x);
    TreeNode tleft;
    tleft.build(arr_y, 0, n - 1, true);
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < idx; i ++) {
        for(; j < n && arr_x[j].x <= segs[i].x; j ++) {
            tleft.update(arr_x[j], true);
        }
        int qcnt = tleft.query(segs[i].y1, segs[i].y2);
        //cerr << segs[i].x * 0.5 << ", " << segs[i].y1 * 0.5 << ", " << segs[i].y2 * 0.5 << " = " << qcnt << " * " << segs[i].sign << endl;
        results[segs[i].idx] += qcnt * segs[i].sign;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < q; i ++) {
        cout << results[i] << endl;
    }
    cerr << (clock() - cl) * 0.001 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A faster solution is to place the points into a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

A region quadtree might be easier to code, but a point quadtree is probably faster.  If using a region quadtree then it can help to stop subdividing the quadtree when the number of points in a quad falls below a threshold (say 16 points)

Each quad stores the number of points it contains, plus either a list of coordinates (for leaf nodes) or pointers to smaller quads.  (You can omit the list of coordinates when the size of the quad reaches 1 as they must all be coincident)

To count the points inside the polygon you look at the largest quad that represents the root of the quadtree.

1. Clip the polygon to the edges of the quad
2. If the polygon does not overlap the quad then return 0
3. If this is a quad of size 1x1 then return the number of points in the quad
4. If the polygon totally encircles the quad then return the number of points in the quad.
5. If this is a leaf node then test each point with the plumb line algorithm
6. Otherwise recursively count the points in each child quad

(If a quad only has one non-empty child then you can skip steps 1,2,3,4,5 to go a little faster)

(The tests in 2 and 4 do not have to be totally accurate)

Answer (score 0):

I would try casting a ray up from the bottom to each point, tracking where it crossed into the polygon (passing a right-to-left segment) or back out of the polygon (passing a left-to-right segment). Something like this:

```
count := 0
For each point (px, py):
   inside := false
   For each query line (x0, y0) -> (x1, y1) where y0 = y1
      if inside
         if x0 <= px < x1 and py > y0
            inside = false
      else 
         if x1 <= px <= x0 and py >= y0
            inside = true
   if inside
      count++
```

The > vs. >= in the two cases is so that a point on the upper edge is considered inside. I haven't actually coded this up to see if it works, but I think the approach is sound.

Comment: the line may cross the polygon multiple times, however you can count the number of intersections (either odd or even). This determines weather the point is inside or outside the polygon. Now one only needs an efficient way of testing for intersections :)

Answer (score 0):

Does trapezoidal decomposition work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I refer you to [Jordan Curve Theorem](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960307.html#intest) and the [Plumb Line Algorithm](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960307.html#intest).

The relevant pseudocode is

```
int crossings = 0
for (each line segment of the polygon)
    if (ray down from (x,y) crosses segment)
        crossings++;
if (crossings is odd)
    return (inside);
else return (outside);
```

Comment: your second link is broken I guess and the algo is basiacly whan I am doing but I "ray" to right

Comment: It looks good.  Whether you ray down or to the right should not matter.